# Android Calling an activity after installation

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an android application. I want to auto start my application after the installation finished.

IN other words I want to call an activity of my own application after installation.

Let me know is it possible? If yes how can I do it ?

Thanks,
Pravin

Comment: Are you using the Eclipse Android plugins? Usually Eclipse will autostart the application after it installs it.

Comment: No, this is not possible for 'normal' installations although, as mentioned above, Eclipse will auto-start it during a debug session.

Comment: Zhehao, I have installed the application on my phone. I want to autostart my application as the installation finished.

Answer (score -1):

Your app isn't in memory after it is installed.  It won't be able to call itself.

Also; after looking at all of your other questions, why do I get the feeling you are writing some sort of malware?  The user owns their phone, not you.

Comment: Eric, I am not writing an malware. My application needs to show the screen lock activity after installation, if the screen password is not set. My application is ready but, I am not able to call it.

Comment: Why don't you just do that on the app's first run? Something running after installation would be very unexpected to the user and make them a little apprehensive about using your app, since it seems very malware-like.